# Loading hyphenation patterns in Texmaker

Tags: hyphenation, babel, texmaker

I've got problems making `TexMaker / MikTeX 2.9` use polish hyphenation rules. As from what I've read on this forum (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/latex-hyphenation)), `babel` package should automatically load polish hyphenation rules after setting:

```
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
```

but it doesn't seem to do so. Until now, I always end up creating a long list of

```
\hyphenation{ wordslist }
```

in the preamble to correct for mis-hyphenated words. Isn't there a way to configure `babel / TexMaker / MikTeX` to load a specific file, i.e. hyph_pl_PL.dic? I recall such a possibility in TeXnic Center (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Check in the `.log` file for a "No hyphenation patterns" message.

Comment: Go to the MiKTeX Settings in your start menu and check if `polish` is enabled. Then, `babel` should work as you directed it. Texmaker has nothing to do with hyphenation in your document, and neither has TeXnicCenter. They only provide spell-checking for your source code.

Comment: Yes, Polish is enabled. Nevertheless some (pretty many) words get hyphenated wrong. Can it be the problem is OS specific? I just installed TexMaker on Windows (created the question while on Linux) and hyphenation looks OK

Comment: @egreg `.log` states hyphenation for polish is loaded

Comment: @mmm Can you produce some examples, please? My suspect is that you're inadvertently changing the language.