# Babel with UKenglish does not use British English hyphenation?

Tags: babel, languages, hyphenation

I am having trouble understanding the hyphenation rules of "babel". According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/latex-hyphenation), selecting either `UKenglish` or `british` should result in Oxford dictionary type hyphenation. But it doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
Foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar produce foo bar.
\end{document}
```

This hyphenates `pro-duce`:
[image]

Which is in accordance with American English, e.g., [Merriam -Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/produce), whereas according to [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/produce) it should be `prod-use`.

Comment: The hyphenation pattern for `produce` is the same in both the American and UKEnglish hyphenation patterns: `pro-duce`. The UKEnglish pattern is based on the Oxford sources as the linked question. Whether there are discrepancies is a separate issue.

Comment: So it's a mistake in the dictionary? The thing is, going through one particular text, I found dozens of discrepancies with the Oxford dictionary, so that makes me wonder whether babel obeys the rules at all.

Comment: See the following question for some detailed discussion: [Why does \usepackage\[british\]{babel} change the hyphenation to wrong?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171084) (In fact I think your question could be considered a duplicate of this.)

Comment: the dictionary used to develop the uk hyphenation patterns doesn't always have the hyphen positions you expect.  see the question [Why does `\usepackage[british]{babel}` change the hyphenation to wrong?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171084/579).  (i'm 3000 miles from my bookshelf, so can't check this particular word, but will try to do so when i return home.)

Comment: Given that the word comes from the Latin `pro` + `ducere` the hyphenation pattern on the webpage linked is almost certainly wrong.