# Hyphenation for British and American English

Tags: languages, hyphenation

I am writing documents with British and American spelling, and I have noticed that some 'common' words are not hyphenated. Examples include 'quar-ter-ly', 'pro-pen-si-ty', 'eu-ro-pean'. This can result in too much interword space (in my opinion), and I have to identify these instances manually.

I want to make sure that I am using everything correctly. For British spelling I use something like:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
```

I know `hyph-utf8` and load `\input{ushyphex}` for AE documents.

I have the following questions:

- For BE, is `loadhyph-en-gb` loaded automatically when `babel` is loaded with british spelling?
- Is there anything else I can do to ensure that some 'common' words are hyphenated.
- If not, is there a way to identify where the typesetting could be improved so that I can create a hyphenation pattern myself?

Some related questions: [LaTeX Hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/latex-hyphenation), [Why does \usepackage[british]{babel} hyphenate the word "alternate" incorrectly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171084/why-does-usepackagebritishbabel-change-the-hyphenation-to-wrong), [How to add global hyphenation rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/how-to-add-global-hyphenation-rules), [Where can I find a list of English hyphenation exceptions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-hyphenation-exceptions?lq=1)

Comment: Two of the three example words you've given -- quarterly and european -- are hyphenated *correctly* by LaTeX either out-of-box or with `babel` loaded with either the `english` (for US-English) or the `british` (for UK-english) option set, i.e., as quar-terly and eu-ro-pean. For English-language documents, the typographic convention is to set `\righthyphenmin` to 3; thus, inserting a hyphenation point before `ly` and `an` would not be considered standard typographic practice. This is, of course, quite different from, say, German language typographic practice.

Comment: @Mico Then I don't understand what's going on. "European" and "Quarterly" do not break (in my bibliography). Only after I specify the pattern myself they break correctly at "Euro-pean" and "Quar-terly".

Comment: In your example, it looks like it's the global option `UKenglish` (which gets passed on to `babel`) that's causing the words quarterly, propensity, and european *not* to get hyphenated at all. Replace `UKenglish` with `english` and the problem disappears.

Comment: @Mico Well, but that is my question: I need to distinguish between AE and BE. If I use `english` US patterns are used. How can I fix this for BE? `loadhyph-en-gb` is supposed to break 90% of all words correctly. Is this loaded automatically with `babel`?

Comment: There are also many words in BE that are not broken correctly: invest-igate, beha-vioural. So my question: are the patterns in `loadhyph-en-gb` wrong or simply not loaded?

Comment: I suspect that TeX's and babel's hyphenation rules are in no way complete, for just about *any* (human) language out there. Whereas a 90% rate of correct hyphenations may sound pretty impressive, it needn't be adequate for any given document. E.g., if your document happens to have a lot of words that fall into the 10% residual, you may not be all that impressed.

Comment: If I set the language to `british`, I get  `in-vest-ig-ate` and `be-ha-vi-oural`. Your TeX system seems to be broken.